# exposing boost::tuple part of class to boost python

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I've been trying to figure out how to expose a property in my class that is a boost::tuple. The tuple is defined as follows:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Action> action_ptr;
typedef boost::tuple<BattleCharacter*, action_ptr > ActionTargetTuple;
```

It's contained with a class defined as follows:

```
class Action : public Cloneable<Action>
{
     public:
          //Irrelevant Code Omitted
          std::vector<ActionTargetTuple> Targets;
}
```

I've seen numerous articles while I was searching about how to convert a boost::tuple into a python tuple, but that's not what I'm looking to do. I want to be able to access the tuple as it exists on the Action class. (I know how to do the vector part).

```
class_<Action, std::auto_ptr<ActionWrapper> >("Action")
        .def("Targets", &Action::Targets)
    ;
```

I expose it simply as above. I figured I might be able to expose it by some variation on the below:

```
 class_<ActionTargetTuple>("ActionTargetTuple")
        .def("get", &ActionTargetTuple::get<int>, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>())
        ;
```

then use get from python, but if it is doable in this way, I'm not sure what the set up needs to be. Does anyone know how to do this/could suggest an alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
...
    .add_property("Targets", & ActionTargetTuple::get, &ActionTargetTuple::set)
```

to make a read-write property using getter/setter methods in c++

If you want to control ownership:

```
namespace bp = boost::python;
...
    .add_property("Targets",
        bp::make_function(&ActionTargetTuple::get, bp::return_value_policy<...>()),
        bp::make_function(&ActionTargetTuple::set, bp::return_value_policy<...>())
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `add_property` as explained in the previous answer, and writing accessor functions, you can consider writing converters for your tuple (between `boost::tuple` and `boost::python::tuple`) and exposing those attributes directly with `def_readonly` or `def_readwrite`. It is worth it if you have many such attributes to expose.

[This](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo#Dynamic_template_to-python_converters.) has a template you adapt can for c++→python conversion (use boost::tuple instead of std::pair), though unless you go c++0x, you have to write out templates for different number of arguments.

If your property is read-write, additionaly define from-python converter, you find examples on the web. [Here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~eudoxos/+junk/tr2/view/head:/py/wrapper/customConverters.cpp#L143) is my code I use to define generic sequence-std::vector converter. In your case, you have to check that the python object is a sequence, that it has the right number of items, that you can extract required types from each of them; and then return new boost::tuple object.

HTH, edx.

P.S. I found [ackward](http://code.google.com/p/ackward/source/browse/src/ackward/core/Tuple.hpp?spec=svna491b0f67a8f904ae4518da727c6a50f52ba52b0&r=a491b0f67a8f904ae4518da727c6a50f52ba52b0) has the converters ready, perhaps you could just reuse it. [Doc here](http://docs.ackward.googlecode.com/hg/html/api/core/tuple.html)